# Azure App Service WebApp to handle all incoming requests independent from hostheader

Tags: azure-web-app-service, iis-8, azure-traffic-manager

Here is what I want to do:
I have a bunch of client URLs like client1.some.com and during maintenance I am redirecting them using Traffic Manager to banner.some.com 
At this point it fails to show them my banner because their host names are not in "Custom Domain" section

I want to find a way to use WebApp for all clients so it won't care from what URL it came from. In that case once I get more clients I don't have to go to my WebApp and add their host names.

By now I have to go to me DNS provider and add awverify records there only after that I am able to add new custom domain on web app.

I want to make IIS ignore host header info and just return index page from default web page.

Thanks 
Ihor

Answer (score 1):

Far as I know, if the client URLs you mentioned have the same root domain or subdomain (e.g. client1.some.com, client2.some.com or client1.a.some.com, client2.a.some.com), you could map a wildcard domain (e.g. *.some.com or *.a.some.com) to your Azure App, in order to meet your requirement. You could follow the steps below to achieve your purpose.

**Create the DNS record(s)**

Please log in to your domain registrar and use their tool to add A CNAME record.
Your CNAME record should be configured as follows:

```
|         FQDN EXAMPLE          | HOST/NAME/HOSTNAME |            Value           |
| ----------------------------- | ------------------ | -------------------------- |
| *.some.com (wildcard)         | *                  | hostname of your Azure App |
| *.a.some.com (wildcard & sub) | *                  | hostname of your Azure App |
```

Please log in to the Azure portal, then configure the wildcard domain for your Azure App.

In addition, after you finish the configuration steps, it could take some time for the changes to take effort.
You could visit http://digwebinterface.com/ to check whether the DNS propagation is working as expected.
For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/).